# how to parse with json?

Tags: android, json, listview, parsing

i have a problem with android json parsing from mysql, when i try to execute my project it show me "org.json.jsonexception end of input at character 0 of"
    this is my parsing code :

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        for(String url: arg0){
            try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            inp = response.getEntity().getContent();
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            error = "ClientProtocolException: " + e.getMessage();
        }catch (IOException e){
            error = "ClientProtocolException: " + e.getMessage();
        }

        }
        BufferedReader reader;

        try{
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inp, "iso-8859-1"),8);
            String line=null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                txt += line+"\n";
            }
            inp.close();

        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            error = "Unsupport Encoding: "+e.getMessage();
        }catch (IOException e){
            error = "Error IO: "+e.getMessage();
        }
        list1 = new ArrayList<Pharm>();

        try{

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(txt);

            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonData = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                Pharm pharm = new Pharm();
                pharm.setNomPharm(jsonData.getString("nomPharm"));
                pharm.setAdressePharm(jsonData.getString("adressePharm"));

                list1.add(pharm);

            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            error = "Error convert to JSON or Error JSON format: "+ e.getMessage();
        }
        return error;
    }
```

i need your help please.

Comment: Can you show us the `JSON` returned?

Comment: That would be a **must** for us to solve the question...

Comment: {
pharmacies: [
{
idPharm: "1",
nomPharm: "pharm1",
adressePharm: "hay saada",
lat: "ssssssss",
lon: "ddddddddd"
}
]
}

Comment: i test it with 127.0.0.1

Comment: i must show some keys of JSON returned in a listView

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Genson for doing this.
For your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.owlike:genson:1.4'
```

and see this page for how it works:

https://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/UserGuide/

666